# Observe the change of selected attributes of objects in LiveData

Tags: android-room, observer-pattern, android-livedata

I am observing following LiveData:

BookDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM books")
LiveData<List<Book>> getBooks();
```

In fragment, I am observing this way (simplified):

```
viewModel.getBooks().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), b -> adapter.setBooks(b));
```

Everything is fine, `adapter` displays all books. However, I need to disable refresh when a flag changes in db (`favourite` column). In other words, when any book is marked as favourite, I do not want `observer` to run. Is there any way how to observe all columns of `book` except for `favourite` column? Adding condition to `observer` is not a good idea, since comparing new state with previous state leads to `O(n^2)` complexity.  Thank you.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. When a table gets updated, `Room` is notified that table has changed, but it does not know which part of the table is changed. You already mentioned diff is not an option. How about either creating a separate table just for `Favourite`, or not using  `LiveData` for this case only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, when any book is marked as favourite, I do not want observer to run.

You can use `.removeObserver()` after you get the first query.

> Is there any way how to observe all columns of book except for favourite column?

Write a sql query in Dao to do that, then observe it, like:

```
SELECT Title, Body FROM TABLENAME;
```

Comment: I need observer, but not for `favourite` flag (i.e. when the name changes, I want observe this change). Query with only two columns does not suits me as well, because I have to know the first value of `favourite` flag.